# CSS direction setting doesn't affect the cursor movement direction in firefox

Tags: html, css

I modified a direction of an input textbox to "rtl", so when I type to the textbox, the text is written from right to left. In Internet explorer when I navigate in the textbox using the right button, the cursor moves to the left side, which is the desired behaviour, but in firefox the cursor moves to right.

What can I do to make firefox switch the navigation directions, just like Internet explorer did?

Thank You.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://caniuse.com/#search=rtl. Looks like you can support Firefox either with the `-moz-` prefix or by using a different `:dir()` pseudo-class.

Comment: Why would the cursor move to the left when you press the right arrow? I think that with [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fm2kzowq/) for instance, Firefox and Chrome have got it right, while IE11 does not.

Comment: @MrLister Because this is the normal behaviour in Arabic countries, which may look very strange for other people :)

Comment: @LászlóHalász Ehm... OK, so in an Arabic word processor, the right arrow → actually moves the cursor to the left ← ? In that case, I stand corrected; I don't know what the solution to the question is, and I'll quietly back off now. Shaking my head.